# The C/C++ VS Code extension switches to the wrong corresponding header/source file when there are similarly named files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have created a very simple C++ project using CMake with a structure that looks as follows:

```
 - include
   - lib1
     - Parser.h
 - src
   - Parser.cpp
```

Normally in VSCode, it is possible to toggle between the header and source file (in my case alt+O), but with this project structure, it is not possible. Instead of finding the header file, it goes to a Windows-specific file:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\parser.h.`

My source file includes its header file, and I've correctly configured my C/C++ configuration provider to the CMake Tools extension.

Is it possible to configure VS Code so that it understands the project structure and can link the two files together?

PS. I have the same issue in Visual Studio. Any tips there would also be appreciated.

Comment: It's been broken for 5 years, doesn't show signs of being fixed https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2635

Comment: This project structure works fine for me in Visual Studio Community with the Visual Assist Addon but that is not free. Since I work at an Academic institution we used to get an Academic licence at a huge discount but eventually they told us this is not for staff so I purchased a personal license with my own funds when it went on sale.

Comment: @AlanBirtles That is hella frustrating, not gonna lie. Guess the best solution for now is to rename the files.

Comment: I'd also try Clangd instead of the stock intellisense, maybe it's saner in this regard. I also remember seeing a standalone "switch header/source" extension, maybe that will work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I will have a look at that! The problem is I also have the same issue with Visual Studio so I decided to restructure the project with different naming of the files so that the IntelliSense doesn't freak out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of issue is tracked by issue ticket [Improve switch header/source matching #2635](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2635). Other issues related to the header/source switching feature can be found by [searching with the corresponding label](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Feature%3A+Switch+Header%2FSource%22). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show your support and increase its prioritization. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

Note that if there's a include path that you want to exclude, use the `C_Cpp.files.exclude` setting.

Comment: Done! The exclude tip is a nice one, I will try that.